# Access: grouping by month/year, how then to display the date properly

Tags: date, ms-access, group-by

I have a query where I want to group by month and year, hence:

```
GROUP BY ... Month(Deductions.USDate), Year(Deductions.USDate) ...
```

But because of the GROUP BY, I need to use these things in the main select query, hence:

```
SELECT Month(Deductions.USDate)&"/"&Year(Deductions.USDate)
```

which gives me 8/2012, 11/2011 etc. Which is great, but it's a string, not a date, so I can't query against it properly.

I've tried doing something like the below, but am getting a type mismatch. What is wrong?

```
CDATE("1/"&Month(Deductions.USDate)&"/"&Year(Deductions.USDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
DateSerial(Year(Deductions.USDate), Month(Deductions.USDate), 1)
```

This returns a date given a year and month, and the day is always set to 1.